# Problems with meta data not picking css media queries

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

The mobile and tablet version of my website are a scaled down version of my desktop site. With the mobile version a fixed navigation bar and slidetoggle navigation come into play.

This all worked for a year until about a month ago and something doesnt seem to be recognising the smaller device sizes and I cannot work out what is wrong. On the mobile version the website contents are squashed to the left. Usually I can fix this with changes to css declarations but any changes I now make dont seem to have any effect.

I have run my code through various code checkers and none have flagged up any major errors.

This is my meta data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> >

<head>
<title>MISSNISAA</title>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0">       
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<link href="http://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=montserrat-light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/rsg8obz.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;   
i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new    
Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;   
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com   
/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-64074269-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/*prepend menu nav icon*/
$("#menu-nav").prepend("<div id='menu-nav-icon'>&#9776</div>");

/*toggle nav*/
$("#menu-nav-icon").on("click", function() {
$(".menu-nav").slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/*prepend menu social icon*/
$("#menu-social").prepend("<div id='menu-social-icon'>&#9776</div>");

/*toggle social*/
$("#menu-social-icon").on("click", function() {
$(".menu-social").slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});

});
</script>

</head>
```

Grateful for any help as I have hit a wall with this.

Just to add the first photo [image: before]is what my website used to look like on the mobile version but now looks like the second photo[image: after]. I have made no changes to the css during this time so I don't see why all of a sudden the media queries don't work.

Comment: Could you add a link to your website? Or at least post some of your CSS?

Comment: http://missnisaa.com/ many thanks

Comment: I've looked at your website in Firefox and Chrome, both on my desktop and phone. Results are mixed, basically. When I turn on the browser's mobile view on my desktop and change the width of the window, the website very noticeably switches style rules at 768px. At a width of 600px, it looks ok in Firefox, but doesn't in Chrome, which better emulates actual smartphone screens. Looking at your style.css, you have *tons* of media rules. I'd ditch all of that. Use two or three, tops.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. I have reduced my media rules down to 3 which has brought back the navigation bar for mobile device and the web page appears better on the screen. Still mostly to the left but at least the issue is improving.